# QooXDoo Tree example

Tags: javascript, tree, qooxdoo

I'm trying to build an application using qooxdoo 3.5, and faced a problem, when instead of adding a tree, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tree' of undefined

The application uses two code parts from demos: widget-tree and layout-hsplit.
I've try to rebuild the app, and to modify config.json file (didn't help, maybe I did something wrong).
The code is here:

```
/**
 * This is the main application class of your custom application "sphinx2"
 *
 * @asset(sphinx2/*)
 */
qx.Class.define("sphinx2.Application",
{
  extend : qx.application.Standalone,

  members :
  {
    /**
     * This method contains the initial application code and gets called 
     * during startup of the application
     * 
     * @lint ignoreDeprecated(alert)
     */
    main : function()
    {
      // Call super class
      this.base(arguments);
      this.addSplitPaneTwoFlexSimple();

    var hBox = new qx.ui.layout.HBox();
      hBox.set(
        {
          spacing: 20
        });
      var container = new qx.ui.container.Composite(hBox);
      this.getRoot().add(container);

      var tree = this.getTree();
      container.add(tree);

      var commandFrame = this.getCommandFrame(tree);
      container.add(commandFrame);

      // Enable logging in debug variant
      if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug"))
      {
        // support native logging capabilities, e.g. Firebug for Firefox
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        // support additional cross-browser console. Press F7 to toggle visibility
        qx.log.appender.Console;
      }
    },

    addSplitPaneTwoFlexSimple : function()
    {
      var splitpane = new qx.ui.splitpane.Pane("horizontal");
      splitpane.setWidth(400);
      splitpane.setHeight(60);
      splitpane.setDecorator("main");
      this.getRoot().add(splitpane, {left:20, top:20});
      // Left
      var leftWidget = new qx.ui.form.TextArea("Flex:1");
      leftWidget.setDecorator(null);
      leftWidget.setWrap(true);
      splitpane.add(leftWidget, 1);
      // Right
      var rightWidget = new qx.ui.form.TextArea("Flex:2");
      rightWidget.setDecorator(null);
      rightWidget.setWrap(true);
      splitpane.add(rightWidget, 2);
    },

     getTree : function()
    {
      var tree = new qx.ui.tree.Tree().set({
        width : 200,
        height : 400,
        draggable: true
      });
      var root = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("root");
      root.setOpen(true);
      tree.setRoot(root);
      var te1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Desktop");
      te1.setOpen(true);
      te1.setIcon("icon/22/places/user-desktop.png");
      root.add(te1);
      var te1_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Files");
      var te1_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Workspace");
      var te1_3 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Network");
      var te1_4 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Trash");
      te1.add(te1_1, te1_2, te1_3, te1_4);
      var te1_2_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Windows (C:)");
      var te1_2_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Documents (D:)");
      te1_2.add(te1_2_1, te1_2_2);
      var te2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Inbox");
      var te2_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Presets");
      var te2_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Sent");
      var te2_3 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Trash");
      for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
        te2_3.add(new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Junk #" + i));
      }
      var te2_4 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Data");
      var te2_5 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Edit");
      te2.add(te2_1, te2_2, te2_3, te2_4, te2_5);
      root.add(te2);
      return tree;
    },
  }
});
```

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I played with code around, and discovered that comma after the second function should've been removed, and tree declaration may be done in the function, not outside of it. Thanks for your time. Resulting working code:

```
/**
 * This is the main application class of your custom application "sphinx2"
 *
 * @asset(sphinx2/*)
 */
qx.Class.define("sphinx2.Application",
{
  extend : qx.application.Standalone,
  /*
  *****************************************************************************
     MEMBERS
  *****************************************************************************
  */
  members :
  {
    /**
     * This method contains the initial application code and gets called 
     * during startup of the application
     * 
     * @lint ignoreDeprecated(alert)
     */
    main : function()
    {
      // Call super class
      this.base(arguments);
      this.addSplitPaneTwoFlexSimple();
      // Enable logging in debug variant
      if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug"))
      {
        // support native logging capabilities, e.g. Firebug for Firefox
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        // support additional cross-browser console. Press F7 to toggle visibility
        qx.log.appender.Console;
      }
    },
      /*
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Below is your actual application code...
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------
      */
    addSplitPaneTwoFlexSimple : function()
    {
      var splitpane = new qx.ui.splitpane.Pane("horizontal");
      splitpane.setWidth(400);
      splitpane.setHeight(60);
      splitpane.setDecorator("main");
      this.getRoot().add(splitpane, {left:20, top:20});
      // Left
      var tree = this.getTree();
      splitpane.add(tree, 1);
      // Right
      var rightWidget = new qx.ui.form.TextArea("Flex:2");
      rightWidget.setDecorator(null);
      rightWidget.setWrap(true);
      splitpane.add(rightWidget, 2);
    },
     getTree : function()
    {
      var tree = new qx.ui.tree.Tree().set({
        draggable: true
      });
      var root = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("root");
      root.setOpen(true);
      tree.setRoot(root);
      var te1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Desktop");
      te1.setOpen(true);
      te1.setIcon("icon/22/places/user-desktop.png");
      root.add(te1);
      var te1_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Files");
      var te1_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Workspace");
      var te1_3 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Network");
      var te1_4 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Trash");
      te1.add(te1_1, te1_2, te1_3, te1_4);
      var te1_2_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Windows (C:)");
      var te1_2_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Documents (D:)");
      te1_2.add(te1_2_1, te1_2_2);
      var te2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Inbox");
      var te2_1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Presets");
      var te2_2 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Sent");
      var te2_3 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Trash");
      for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
        te2_3.add(new qx.ui.tree.TreeFile("Junk #" + i));
      }
      var te2_4 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Data");
      var te2_5 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Edit");
      te2.add(te2_1, te2_2, te2_3, te2_4, te2_5);
      root.add(te2);
      return tree;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the qx.ui.tree.Tree dependency isn't included in the generated app. Are you sure you used the appropriate generator job, i.e. `generate.py source` for the development version (`sphinx2/source/index.html`)?

Answer (score 0):

Do a ./generate distclean, then a ./generate source-all, and see if the error still happens - didn't happen to me, and I did experience bad builds due to damaged cache in the past.

What I got when building and running the code above whas an error saying getCommandFrame() is not a function - most likely because you forgot to include it.